# Testing hypethesis

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have search through archive questions but none is simple enough to explain the concepts to me in a self-study situation. I am new to this statistics and I find this topic difficult to understand even with the textbooks. Can you help?

A coin tossing yields 30 heads and 70 tails. Taking 1% significance level, test whether or not the coin is unbiased. State null hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis. Assume identical conditions of tossing.

I thought the null hypothesis, simply put is: "Test whether coin is unbiased i.e. fair"
and the alternate hypothesis is: "Test whether coin is no unbiased, i.e. unfair).

Is that all?

**The actual question is here, and I am not sure if it is wrongly framed for a person like me to answer.**

> Blockquote

[image]

> Blockquote

Comment: "Test whether ..." is never a hypothesis. "The coins is fair" is a hypothesis, "Test whether the coin is fair" is not a hypothesis, it is instructions.

Comment: Ok @Thomas Andrews, what would be the answer to the question or how do I go about answering?

Comment: Good luck. I'm sorry my attempt to help you clarify your question was not enough for you!